# PrimeNg and multi-select component event handling

Tags: angular, primeng

I have a tree control, homes, and multi select primeng control, cars in the homes.

The selections in the tree control, as they change, will impact the entries in the multi-select component. As different homes are selected and unselected, the list of cars will change. To get the list of cars, based on selected homes is an http call.

By the time, the data has to be retrieved by the time the user opens up the multi-select.

When is the correct time to send the http request to ensure that data is ready for the dropdown? Or how else should I approach this?

Answer (score 0):

Your most responsive method would be to load the data and filter it based on the tree control selected value(s).  Otherwise you're always going to be playing catch-up.

Comment: Understand, as the user is changing selection on the tree control, for every event, I can not be making an HTTP request to receive the corresponding cars. It is too much latency.

Comment: I'm not saying make a request for every time it changes.  I mean load all the data, and filter the array of cars based on the selection of the home.